# Longtable and landscape do not work

Tags: longtable, rotating, landscape, sidewaystable

I have a really wide table that I want to split into proper amount of pages (I have no clue whether 2 pages is enough). I've researched for quite some time and found that the command `longtable` should be sufficient. However that is not the case and I can't get it to work.

Furthermore I want the table to be vertical instead of horizontal. To do this, I've tried using `landscape` in the code and admittedly it does change it to vertical, however it just does not look right.

I've tried `sidewaystable` as well as `rotating` package manually (I believe the command sideways table is part of rotating) but to no avail.. The end result just.. sucks.

Here's my "test" code (it needs to go into a bigger document, however I want this to work on it's own before I try that).

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{rllllllllllllll}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{T (C)} & Ammonia & Trimethylamine & n-hexane & Pyridine & p-xylene (24.85 °C - 59.85 °C) & p-xylene (13.28 °C - 179.23 °C) & p-xylene (58.29 °C - 139.29 °C) & 2,6-dimethylpyridine & 1,3,5-trimethylbenzene & 1,2,4-trimethylbenzene & 3,5-dimethylpyridine & Isodurene & Durene & 4-methylquinoline \\ 
0 & 3193.85 & 680.67 & 45.32 & 4.46 & 1.84 & 1.78 & 1.73 & 0.98 & 0.39 & 0.32 & 0.3 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.00 \\ 
5 & 3832.56 & 824.26 & 58.89 & 6.23 & 2.59 & 2.52 & 2.47 & 1.43 & 0.58 & 0.48 & 0.45 & 0.04 & 0.01 & 0.00 \\ 
10 & 4568.36 & 990.51 & 75.69 & 8.58 & 3.59 & 3.53 & 3.46 & 2.06 & 0.84 & 0.7 & 0.66 & 0.06 & 0.02 & 0.00 \\ 
15 & 5411.1 & 1181.72 & 96.26 & 11.65 & 4.92 & 4.86 & 4.77 & 2.92 & 1.22 & 1.02 & 0.94 & 0.11 & 0.05 & 0.00 \\ 
20 & 6371.04 & 1400.26 & 121.23 & 15.62 & 6.65 & 6.6 & 6.5 & 4.08 & 1.73 & 1.45 & 1.33 & 0.17 & 0.09 & 0.00 \\ 
25 & 7458.82 & 1648.59 & 151.26 & 20.68 & 8.89 & 8.86 & 8.74 & 5.6 & 2.42 & 2.03 & 1.86 & 0.27 & 0.16 & 0.00 \\ 
30 & 8685.43 & 1929.22 & 187.1 & 27.07 & 11.76 & 11.75 & 11.62 & 7.6 & 3.34 & 2.81 & 2.56 & 0.41 & 0.27 & 0.01 \\ 
35 & 10062.18 & 2244.71 & 229.54 & 35.06 & 15.38 & 15.41 & 15.26 & 10.18 & 4.54 & 3.84 & 3.48 & 0.62 & 0.44 & 0.01 \\ 
40 & 11600.64 & 2597.65 & 279.44 & 44.94 & 19.93 & 19.99 & 19.83 & 13.48 & 6.11 & 5.18 & 4.67 & 0.92 & 0.7 & 0.02 \\ 
45 & 13312.63 & 2990.68 & 337.71 & 57.06 & 25.58 & 25.69 & 25.51 & 17.64 & 8.12 & 6.91 & 6.21 & 1.33 & 1.09 & 0.03 \\ 
50 & 15210.18 & 3426.44 & 405.33 & 71.8 & 32.54 & 32.69 & 32.51 & 22.86 & 10.67 & 9.1 & 8.16 & 1.9 & 1.63 & 0.05 \\ 
55 & 17305.47 & 3907.57 & 483.31 & 89.58 & 41.05 & 41.25 & 41.05 & 29.33 & 13.88 & 11.87 & 10.63 & 2.65 & 2.4 & 0.07 \\ 
60 & 19610.83 & 4436.73 & 572.74 & 110.86 & 51.38 & 51.6 & 51.41 & 37.29 & 17.89 & 15.34 & 13.71 & 3.66 & 3.44 & 0.11 \\ 
65 & 22138.65 & 5016.55 & 674.76 & 136.16 & 63.83 & 64.05 & 63.87 & 46.99 & 22.83 & 19.63 & 17.53 & 4.97 & 4.83 & 0.16 \\ 
70 & 24901.42 & 5649.65 & 790.52 & 166.03 & 78.73 & 78.91 & 78.73 & 58.72 & 28.89 & 24.89 & 22.22 & 6.67 & 6.67 & 0.24 \\ 
75 & 27911.6 & 6338.62 & 921.27 & 201.07 & 96.44 & 96.52 & 96.37 & 72.81 & 36.26 & 31.31 & 27.94 & 8.83 & 9.05 & 0.34 \\ 
80 & 31181.67 & 7086.01 & 1068.25 & 241.93 & 117.38 & 117.27 & 117.15 & 89.6 & 45.15 & 39.06 & 34.87 & 11.56 & 12.08 & 0.48 \\ 
85 & 34724.05 & 7894.32 & 1232.77 & 289.3 & 141.98 & 141.57 & 141.48 & 109.49 & 55.8 & 48.38 & 43.2 & 14.97 & 15.9 & 0.68 \\ 
90 & 38551.08 & 8766.02 & 1416.16 & 343.92 & 170.72 & 169.85 & 169.81 & 132.91 & 68.48 & 59.48 & 53.16 & 19.19 & 20.64 & 0.94 \\ 
95 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{42675} & 9703.51 & 1619.79 & 406.57 & 204.14 & 202.61 & 202.62 & 160.3 & 83.48 & 72.64 & 64.99 & 24.36 & 26.46 & 1.29 \\ 
100 & 47107.9 & 10709.12 & 1845.03 & 478.09 & 242.79 & 240.34 & 240.42 & 192.16 & 101.12 & 88.14 & 78.95 & 30.64 & 33.53 & 1.74 \\ 
\caption{Dadada}
\label{vaporpressure}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If I run your example the table is landscape but because of the wide headings in row 1 still too wide even for the landscape, you need to allow your headings to linebreak

Answer (score 1):

With the following modifications, you can squeeze the table onto a single page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Dadada}
\label{vaporpressure}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r
                S[table-format=5.2]
                *{2}{S[table-format=4.2]}
                *{6}{S[table-format=3.2]}
                *{4}{S[table-format=2.2]}
                S[table-format=1.2]@{}}
\toprule
\thead{T\\ (C)}
  & {\thead{Ammonia}} 
    & {\thead{Tri-\\methyl-\\amine}} 
      & {\thead{n-hexane} }
        & {\thead{Pyri-\\dine} }
          & {\thead{p-xylene\\ \textsuperscript{[a]}}} 
            & {\thead{p-xylene\\ \textsuperscript{[b]}} }
              & {\thead{p-xylene\\ \textsuperscript{[c]}} }
                & {\thead{2,6-di-\\methyl-\\pyridine} }
                  & {\thead{1,3,5-tri-\\methyl-\\benzene} }
                    & {\thead{1,2,4-tri-\\methyl-\\benzene}} 
                      & {\thead{3,5-di-\\methyl-\\pyridine} }
                        & {\thead{Iso-\\durene} }
                          & {\thead{Durene} }
                            & {\thead{4-methyl-\\quinoline}} \\ 
\midrule
0 & 3193.85 & 680.67 & 45.32 & 4.46 & 1.84 & 1.78 & 1.73 & 0.98 & 0.39 & 0.32 & 0.3 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.00 \\ 
5 & 3832.56 & 824.26 & 58.89 & 6.23 & 2.59 & 2.52 & 2.47 & 1.43 & 0.58 & 0.48 & 0.45 & 0.04 & 0.01 & 0.00 \\ 
10 & 4568.36 & 990.51 & 75.69 & 8.58 & 3.59 & 3.53 & 3.46 & 2.06 & 0.84 & 0.7 & 0.66 & 0.06 & 0.02 & 0.00 \\ 
15 & 5411.1 & 1181.72 & 96.26 & 11.65 & 4.92 & 4.86 & 4.77 & 2.92 & 1.22 & 1.02 & 0.94 & 0.11 & 0.05 & 0.00 \\ 
20 & 6371.04 & 1400.26 & 121.23 & 15.62 & 6.65 & 6.6 & 6.5 & 4.08 & 1.73 & 1.45 & 1.33 & 0.17 & 0.09 & 0.00 \\ 
25 & 7458.82 & 1648.59 & 151.26 & 20.68 & 8.89 & 8.86 & 8.74 & 5.6 & 2.42 & 2.03 & 1.86 & 0.27 & 0.16 & 0.00 \\ 
30 & 8685.43 & 1929.22 & 187.1 & 27.07 & 11.76 & 11.75 & 11.62 & 7.6 & 3.34 & 2.81 & 2.56 & 0.41 & 0.27 & 0.01 \\ 
35 & 10062.18 & 2244.71 & 229.54 & 35.06 & 15.38 & 15.41 & 15.26 & 10.18 & 4.54 & 3.84 & 3.48 & 0.62 & 0.44 & 0.01 \\ 
40 & 11600.64 & 2597.65 & 279.44 & 44.94 & 19.93 & 19.99 & 19.83 & 13.48 & 6.11 & 5.18 & 4.67 & 0.92 & 0.7 & 0.02 \\ 
45 & 13312.63 & 2990.68 & 337.71 & 57.06 & 25.58 & 25.69 & 25.51 & 17.64 & 8.12 & 6.91 & 6.21 & 1.33 & 1.09 & 0.03 \\ 
50 & 15210.18 & 3426.44 & 405.33 & 71.8 & 32.54 & 32.69 & 32.51 & 22.86 & 10.67 & 9.1 & 8.16 & 1.9 & 1.63 & 0.05 \\ 
55 & 17305.47 & 3907.57 & 483.31 & 89.58 & 41.05 & 41.25 & 41.05 & 29.33 & 13.88 & 11.87 & 10.63 & 2.65 & 2.4 & 0.07 \\ 
60 & 19610.83 & 4436.73 & 572.74 & 110.86 & 51.38 & 51.6 & 51.41 & 37.29 & 17.89 & 15.34 & 13.71 & 3.66 & 3.44 & 0.11 \\ 
65 & 22138.65 & 5016.55 & 674.76 & 136.16 & 63.83 & 64.05 & 63.87 & 46.99 & 22.83 & 19.63 & 17.53 & 4.97 & 4.83 & 0.16 \\ 
70 & 24901.42 & 5649.65 & 790.52 & 166.03 & 78.73 & 78.91 & 78.73 & 58.72 & 28.89 & 24.89 & 22.22 & 6.67 & 6.67 & 0.24 \\ 
75 & 27911.6 & 6338.62 & 921.27 & 201.07 & 96.44 & 96.52 & 96.37 & 72.81 & 36.26 & 31.31 & 27.94 & 8.83 & 9.05 & 0.34 \\ 
80 & 31181.67 & 7086.01 & 1068.25 & 241.93 & 117.38 & 117.27 & 117.15 & 89.6 & 45.15 & 39.06 & 34.87 & 11.56 & 12.08 & 0.48 \\ 
85 & 34724.05 & 7894.32 & 1232.77 & 289.3 & 141.98 & 141.57 & 141.48 & 109.49 & 55.8 & 48.38 & 43.2 & 14.97 & 15.9 & 0.68 \\ 
90 & 38551.08 & 8766.02 & 1416.16 & 343.92 & 170.72 & 169.85 & 169.81 & 132.91 & 68.48 & 59.48 & 53.16 & 19.19 & 20.64 & 0.94 \\ 
95 & 42675 & 9703.51 & 1619.79 & 406.57 & 204.14 & 202.61 & 202.62 & 160.3 & 83.48 & 72.64 & 64.99 & 24.36 & 26.46 & 1.29 \\ 
100 & 47107.9 & 10709.12 & 1845.03 & 478.09 & 242.79 & 240.34 & 240.42 & 192.16 & 101.12 & 88.14 & 78.95 & 30.64 & 33.53 & 1.74 \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{15}{l}{\textsuperscript{[a]} (24.85 °C - 59.85 °C); \textsuperscript{[b]} (13.28 °C - 179.23 °C); \textsuperscript{[c]} (58.29 °C - 139.29 °C) }
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: And if it were to be a subfile in a bigger .tex document? How would I incorporate this table :)

Comment: When I try to, I get the error "Misplaced alignment tab character &." for only the & {\thead{4-methyl-\\quinoline}} \\  row in the code. I am not sure what causes this error. The code works in a seperator document or .tex file, but when I compile the main file it does not.